# Overriding liferay login jsp using a hook

Tags: liferay-6

I'm trying to override a JSP in Liferay 6.1, namely html/portlet/login/login.jsp.

I have

```
created a hook (using Eclipse)
added <custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir> to liferay-hook.xml
created the abovementioned directory structure
copied login.jsp there and modified it
deployed the hook
(restarted the server, you never know...)
```

But i am not able to see the modified login page.Where i am doing wrong.I am very new to this liferay.I am getting very much confuse with this.Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the 'created the abovementioned directory structure' step - what folders did you create and where?

Answer (score 0):

[Implementing Hooks in Liferay-portal-6.0.5](http://michi-path.blogspot.in/2012/03/implementing-hooks-in-liferay-portal.html)

The above links targets on creation of a hook for custom login page. Hope this helps..!!!